# UITableViewController Grouped Property Not Working

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have two UITableViewControllers.  In the first UITableView, once a user selects a cell, a new UITableViewController is pushed.  I have set both UITableViews to "Grouped" in IB.  However, when the second UITableViewController is pushed, it appears as a "Plain" UITableView.  Is there a way to fix this?

Just as a sanity check, I changed the code so that the second UITableViewController is pushed not from the first UITableViewController, and it does appear to be "Grouped".  Is there a reason this is happening?

Code From UITableViewController that is pushing second UITableViewController:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

   if ([cell.text isEqualToString:@"Long Term Disability"]) { 
    LongDisabilityTableView *ldvc = [LongDisabilityTableView alloc]; 
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ldvc animated:YES];
   }
    if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Short Term Disability"]) {

        ShortDisabilityTableView *sdvc = [ShortDisabilityTableView alloc]; 
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:sdvc animated:YES];
    }

}
```

Comment: Show the code you are using to push to these controllers, and if you are creating the UITableViews from code or not.

Comment: The UITableView is created in IB.  The data being loaded is in the code, but I don't think that's where the problem is.

Comment: Post your code anyway, you may be doing something to trigger Plain instead of Grouped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are pushing to a `UITableViewController`, you can force the table to be grouped by doing one of the following:

### Init

```
MyTableController *grouped = [[MyTableController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

### Super

This needs to be added to a `UITableViewController`.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped]; /* This is where the magic happens */
    if (self) {
        self.title = @"My Grouped Table";
    }
    return self;
}
```

### Double Check

Make sure that you are not placing your `UITableView` on a `UIViewController`.

Make sure that you are calling the correct controller in your code (from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`)

### Update, added after code

Well there's one reason right there, you aren't using init. See my first example above.

You should also change your code to this:

```
/*  This assumes that your Long Term Disability cell is at index 0
    and that your Short Term Disability cell is at index 1. 
 */
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch ( indexPath.row )
    {
        case 0: /* @"Long Term Disability" */

            LongDisabilityTableView *ldvc = [[LongDisabilityTableView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped]; 
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:ldvc animated:YES];
            break;

        case 1: /* @"Short Term Disability" */

            ShortDisabilityTableView *sdvc = [[ShortDisabilityTableView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:sdvc animated:YES];
            break;
    }
}
```